# Can XHR reuse persistent connections opened during page load?

Tags: tcp, xmlhttprequest, persistent-connection

When loading a page a browser will open several persistent TCP connections to the server. When executing javascript later and making XHR requests does the browser reuse these connections or does every XHR request always imply a new TCP connection that is closed afterwards?